# What DateTime format is this called? "/Date(1565929330662)/"

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf

I received this DateTime format from a WebAPI output. The back end is from Microsoft .NET WCF.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Id": "Random.Real4",
            "TagName": "Random",
            "Parameter": "Real4",
            "LastValue": {
                "IsError": false,
                "TSUTC": "/Date(1565929330662)/",
                "Value": 12780.19,
                "AggMark": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a conventional name for such Date Time format?

Thanks

Comment: It's a POSIX timestamp in milliseconds surrounded by `/Date(...)/`.

Comment: `1565929330662` is today date in milliseconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its UNIX timestamp. This timestamp can be converted to date and time

Follow the link for more details,
https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Answer (score 2):

Convert milliseconds date to date in `C#`

```
var date = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).AddMilliseconds(double.Parse("1565929330662")).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

output 
`2019-22-16 04:22:10`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Epoch time (or [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) - `the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Thursday, 1 January 1970`. Paste the timestamp into [a converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to see what it represents. You can use a library like [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) to parse this and use it in your app.

Answer (score 1):

is this something related to your access token .Web api returns token expiration time in the above format called Epoch time (or Unix time).